# Execute failed error from twitter search on KNIME

Tags: twitter, knime

I have an error on KNIME. I am trying to scrape the tweets from twitter but I have this error:

> << ERROR Twitter Search       0:2        Execute failed: 400:The
> request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why.
> This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate
> limiting (https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a
> request without authentication is considered invalid and you will get
> this response. message - Bad Authentication data. code - 215>>

Comment: It is impossible to debug code that you don't show us.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This errors is due to you are issuing your request without authentication, first you need to authenticate against twitter and after you're be able to issue the request properly.